# Sever sent events are not triggering inside while loop

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I am trying to send some data(Which is in database) from server to client. I am receiving message at client side if that echo is outside while loop.

```
while ( $fetchGetValues = @mysql_fetch_assoc ( $rsGetValues ) ) {
  echo "data: ".$fetchGetValues['gm_id']."\n\n";
  flush();
}
```

I am sure that it is entering into while loop. I cross checked thrice. Can anyone tell what might be the problem?

Note: I used same `echo "data: ".$fetchGetValues['gm_id']."\n\n";  flush();` outside the while loop and it sent message to client.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to output immediately, remove the `flush()` function and try out.